# Python Unittest no module found error - importing in the file that is being tested

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a file structure like this

```
src 
 -main
   -python 
     -config
       -config.py
     -file.py
 -test
  -file_test.py
```

The file.py imports config.py as `import config.config`

However this causes an issue when running the unittest with the error `no module named config.confg`
My testing file imports file.py as `from src.main.python import file` correctly. How would I fix this error?

Note: I tried changing `import config.config` to `from src.main.python.config import config` which fixes the testing but then causes an issue when trying to run the actual python code. I end up getting an error of `No module named src`

Comment: how about your setup.py

Answer (score 0):

you can try

`from src.main.python.config import config`

or

`import src.main.python.config.config`

instead of

`import config.config`

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did try this, but then I get an error when running the python script that there is no module named src

Comment: Can you pls send the actual code for your test imports